# how to solve the emitter can't send the 'list' or 'set' in webots?these data is important to me

Tags: webots

hey，everyone！when I want to use the emitter to send some 'list' or 'set' type data,I got errors.it told me these types data are unsupported to send for emitter.but these data is important for my code.I must use all robots's data to updata my nerual network,I use emitters to send their data,but i meet the question,how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to serialize your data in order to be able to send it with the [Emitter](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/emitter) (or in general to transmit data between two processes), i.e. your object needs to be translated to a flat string or byte stream.

You can write your own code to convert your list to string in the Emitter controller and then recover the list in the Receiver controller.
Otherwise you can find many libraries or modules that provides this functionality.

For example for Python there is the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module that can be used for serialization. Here is an example:

Emitter code:

```py
from controller import Robot, Emitter
import json
...
emitter_robot = Robot()
emitter_device = emitter_robot.getDevice('emitter')
timestep = emitter_robot.getBasicTimeStep()
...
while self.step(timeStep) != -1:
    my_list = {'first': 1, 'second': 2}
    emitter_device.send(json.dumps(my_list))
```

Receiver code:

```py
from controller import Robot, Receiver
import json
...
receiver_robot = Robot()
timestep = emitter_robot.getBasicTimeStep()
receiver_device = receiver_robot.getDevice('receiver')
receiver_device.enable(timeStep)
...
while receiver_robot.step(timeStep) != -1:
    while receiver_device.getQueueLength() > 0:
        data = receiver_device.getString()
        my_list = json.loads(data)
        receiver_device.nextPacket()
```

*Disclaimer: I am a [Webots](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots) developer working at [Cyberbotics](https://www.cyberbotics.com/).*